# Carriage return or new line in xml comments

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to find a way to put carriage returns/new lines in the xml comments of my properties.  Right now, when the tip appears in intellisense, the line are all bunched up, making it hard to read:
[image]

I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

Here's what the xml looks like:

```
///<summary>
///Question:
/// 'Are you sure you wish to delete the selected |Value|'
///<para>Replace |Value| with the entity name of choice.</para>
///</summary>
internal const string ConfirmEntityDelete = "Are you sure you wish to delete the selected |Value|?";
```

I understand that xml doesn't recognize whitespace so I can't use empty `<para>` tags.  The only way I've had any luck is by using the para tags with a period `<para>.</para>`.  It is visible in the tip but at least it makes it a tad more readable.

I've looked here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and found all the tags that can be used, and have tried them all, but haven't had any luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same suggestion as @AndyT, but to be well-formed XML, it would need to be `<br/>`.

Comment: Yes, both alone and inside the `<para>` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe something like this? It adds a carriage return but not an empty line though.

```
/// <summary> 
/// Your main comment 
/// <para>&#160;</para> 
/// <para>The rest of the comment</para> 
/// </summary> 
public void CommentMethod()
{
}
```

**EDIT:** Found and added character to display new line. I knew I had done something similar before.

Comment: I tried this but it seems to remove the empty tags and makes it look the same as without the `<para>` tags.

Comment: That's it!  Been looking for this for a long time now, thanks!

Comment: Just to add, the other way you could achieve this is to use a non-breaking space by using key combination Alt+255, this produces the same result but without having to copy of paste &#160; every time.